# Converting char[,] array to char**

Tags: c#, arrays, char

Converting string to `char*` is easy in c#

```
string p = "qwerty";
fixed(char* s = p)
```

But does anyone know how to convert `char[,]` into `char**` in c#?

Comment: In most languages 2 dimensional arrays aren't stored in a way that is compatible with char**. I'm not sure of C#'s implementation, but I'd suspect the 2D array is just stored as a contiguous block of length `x*y`, which would be equivalent to a char*.

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano   you are awesome :D I had to use                     char[,] p = new char[2, 2];
            p[0, 0] = '1';
            p[0, 1] = '2';
            p[1, 0] = '3';
            p[1, 1] = '4';

            fixed (char* s = p) and it works.

Comment: @bobby you night want to add it as answer. Else OP could do that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That comment was mostly based off something I read in WG21 a while ago. OP should probably answer it, since he has some evidence that this was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below shows how to convert a `char[,]` array to a pointer. It also demonstrates how chars can be written into the array and retrieved through the pointer. You could also write using the pointer and read using the array. It's all the same, as it references the same data.

```
            char[,] twoD = new char[2, 2];

            // Store characters in a two-dimensional array
            twoD[0, 0] = 'a';
            twoD[0, 1] = 'b';
            twoD[1, 0] = 'c';
            twoD[1, 1] = 'd';

            // Convert to pointer
            fixed (char* ptr = twoD)
            {
                // Access characters throught the pointer
                char ch0 = ptr[0]; // gets the character 'a'
                char ch1 = ptr[1]; // gets the character 'b'
                char ch2 = ptr[2]; // gets the character 'c'
                char ch3 = ptr[3]; // gets the character 'd'
            }
```